# MYSQL 5.6 get latest data of each user

Tags: mysql

My Database table is as shown below. I need to get latest mark of each student. Latest entry is the row with maximum `udate` and maximum `oder`. (The `oder` will be incremented by one on each entry with same date)

[image]

In my example, I have two students `Mujeeb, Zakariya` and two subjects `ENGLISH, MATHS`. I need to get latest mark of each student for each subject. My expectd result is as follows

[image]

My sample data is

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `students`;
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students` (
    `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `udate` date NOT NULL,
    `oder` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `Subject` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `mark` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


  INSERT INTO `students` (`uid`, `udate`, `oder`, `name`, `Subject`, `mark`) VALUES
  (1, '2021-08-01', 1, 'Mujeeb', 'ENGLISH', 10),
  (2, '2021-08-01', 1, 'Zakariya', 'ENGLISH', 20),
  (3, '2021-08-10', 2, 'Mujeeb', 'ENGLISH', 50),
  (4, '2021-08-11', 2, 'Zakariya', 'ENGLISH', 60),
  (5, '2021-08-02', 1, 'Mujeeb', 'ENGLISH', 100),
  (6, '2021-08-03', 1, 'Zakariya', 'ENGLISH', 110),
  (7, '2021-08-10', 1, 'Mujeeb', 'ENGLISH', 500),
  (8, '2021-08-11', 1, 'Zakariya', 'ENGLISH', 600),
  (9, '2021-08-01', 2, 'Mujeeb', 'MATHS', 100),
  (10, '2021-08-01', 2, 'Zakariya', 'MATHS', 75),
  (11, '2021-08-10', 3, 'Mujeeb', 'MATHS', 50),
  (12, '2021-08-11', 3, 'Zakariya', 'MATHS', 60);
```

Comment: I have found solution @ [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql). But in my case how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Comment: No, a slight difference.  In that post, latest entry determined by id, but in my case it is with both `udate` and `oder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM students s1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM students s2
  WHERE s2.name = s1.name AND s2.Subject = s1.Subject
    AND (s2.udate > s1.udate OR (s2.udate = s1.udate AND s2.oder > s1.oder))  
);
```

Or with a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM students s1
WHERE s1.uid = (
  SELECT s2.uid
  FROM students s2
  WHERE s2.name = s1.name AND s2.Subject = s1.Subject
  ORDER BY s2.udate DESC, s2.oder DESC LIMIT 1
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6f536a9095d26c71939df562ae683c84).

Comment: As I have over 50MB data, which would be more efficient?

Comment: @Sam usually EXISTS performs better because it returns as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: In first example what happening `SELECT 1`. pls give me some explanation

Comment: @Sam `1` is not significant. It could be `0` or `*` or even `null`. What is important here is that SELECT inside EXISTS returns or not a row. You can find more about it here: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-exists/

Comment: @Sam This is the condition for the max udate and if there are more than 1 max udates then get the max oder.

Answer (score 1):

As ROW_NUMBER() function doesn't work at lower version of MySQL, So alternate way of row_number() is used for this solution.

```
-- MySQL (v5.6)
SELECT p.uid, p.udate, p.oder, p.name, p.Subject, p.mark
FROM (SELECT @row_no := IF((@prev_val = t.name && @prev_val1 = t.Subject), @row_no + 1, 1) AS row_number
                 , @prev_val := t.name AS name
                 , @prev_val1 := t.Subject AS Subject
                 , t.mark
                 , t.oder
                 , t.uid
                 , t.udate
            FROM students t,
            (SELECT @row_no := 0) x,
            (SELECT @prev_val := '') y,
            (SELECT @prev_val1 := '') z
            ORDER BY t.name, t.Subject, t.udate DESC, t.oder DESC ) p
WHERE p.row_number = 1
ORDER BY p.name, p.Subject;
```

Please check the url http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5befe/18

Comment: Hi @Sam My current solution is version 5.6 compatible and hope it'll meet your expectations.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase explanation added.